# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "worden" und "geworden"

Tags: word-usage, participle

Laut [canoonet.eu](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/werden:V:sein) ist das Partizip von *werden* entweder *worden* oder *geworden*. Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den beiden?

Kann man immer *geworden* benutzen, oder gibt es Fälle, in denen *geworden* falsch ist?

Comment: Faustregel: Ich bin *ge*boren worden. Ich bin 11 Jahre alt *ge*worden. Ich bin *ge*hört worden, aber dann aufgrund des Lärms taub *ge*worden. Nach einem Verb (das als in der Partizip Perfekt Form meist mit `ge` beginnt), verwende `worden`; nach einem Substantiv oder Adjektive, verwende `geworden`.

Comment: Man sollte sich aber nicht auf das `ge` in der Verbform verlassen; mir ist gerade noch ein Beispiel eingefallen: Nachdem ich immer wieder überhört worden bin, ist meine Stimme sehr laut `ge`worden. Überhört als Partizip Perfekt fängt eben nicht mit `ge` an; es kommt auf das Verb an, nicht auf die Vorsilbe `ge`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The straight and simple explanation:

- *worden* is used to build a ***passive voice*** form of some verb ***in the past***;
- *geworden* is used to build a ***past tense*** form of the verb *werden* ***itself***.

*Example:*
The passive voice in the past:

> It was built. = Es ist gebaut worden.

but the conjugation of *werden* (to become) in the past (indicative):

> It has got dark. = Es ist dunkel geworden.

Comment: it should be it has got**ten** dark

Comment: @Ev.Kounis should it? in my dialect (British English) it reads fine.

Comment: @jambrothers It seems that it is an BrE vs AmE issue. [See this for more](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten). My bad.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis ah that would explain it. BrE does hide the distinction between perfect and imperfect past though.

Comment: so what is the difference between `Es ist gebaut worden.` and `Es wurde gebaut` ?

Answer (score 14):

In [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/werden_%28Konjugation%29) heißt es:

> Anmerkung: 
>       Als Hilfsverb lautet das Partizip Perfekt „worden“ und als Vollverb „geworden“!

Das war es.

Answer (score 6):

Die Formulierung von Wictionary mag akademisch sein, sie taugt aber für die Praxis nichts.

Partizip Perfekt + worden: Ich bin gefragt worden, ob ...

Keine Verbform vorher: geworden: Ich bin krank geworden.

Comment: Ich versuche vergeblich, den Unterschied zwischen der Wiktionary-Anmerkung aus [c.p.s Antwort](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/10654/5999) und der Regel in dieser Antwort zu finden. Die Wiktionary-Formulierung ist sehr klar verständlich, während diese Antwort irgendwie verwirrend ist; steckt denn noch ein versteckter Unterschied hier drin, der diese Definition auf irgendeine Weise "für die Praxis tauglicher" macht?

Comment: Ich erinnere mich, als Kommentar ein Beispiel gegeben zu haben, das zeigt, dass man die grammatische Funktion von „werden“ verstehen muss, aber wenn ich nicht zu dumm war, den Kommentar abzuschicken, dann ist er wohl gelöscht worden.

Answer (score 3):

Es wird deshalb "worden" benutzt, um eine Partizip II-Doppelung - z.B. ein zweimaliges "ge-" (im regelmäßigen Fall) - zu vermeiden. "Worden" ist insofern eine Art Schrumpfpartizip II (ohne Präfix).

Comment: Kannst Du das etwas klarer formulieren,vielleicht mit einem Beispiel? Wo wäre das doppelte "ge"? "gegeworden"?

Comment: Wir sagen ja nicht: "Ich bin vom Ball getroffen geworden", sondern eben "... getroffen worden". Das gilt ebenso für unregelmäßige Partizipien (die nicht mit der Versilbe "ge-" gebildet werden): "Etwas ist vergessen worden" (und eben nicht: "vergessen geworden").

Comment: Bitte editiere Deine Antwort. Nicht alle Kommentare werden immer automatisch angezeigt.